# Point-set Topology Qualifying exam problem

Tags: general-topology

Here is a qualifying exam problem that I am having trouble with.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**(a)** Let $G$ be a topological group with subgroup $H$. Let $G/ H$ denote the quotient
space of $G$ consisting of all cosets $gH$ of $H$ in $G.$ Show that the quotient map
$q : G \rightarrow G/H$ is open.

**(b)** Let $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ denote the group of all non-singular real $n \times n$ matrices, and let $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ denote the subgroup of matrices with determinant $1$. Show that the quotient space $GL(n, \mathbb{R})/SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Who on earth uses $G=H$ instead of $G/H$ for the quotient?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) Let $U$ be an open set in $G$. You need to show that $q[U]$ is open in $G/H$, which means showing that $q^{-1}\big[q[U]\big]$ is open in $G$. Now use the fact that

$$q^{-1}\big[q[U]\big]=\bigcup_{g\in U}gH=UH=\bigcup_{h\in H}Uh\;.$$

(b) Show that if $A,B\in GL(n,\Bbb R)$ are in the same coset of $SL(n,\Bbb R)$, then $\det A=\det B$, so that $\det:GL(n,\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ induces a map $$d:GL(n,\Bbb R)/SL(n,\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}:[A]\mapsto\det A\;,$$ where I write $[A]$ for the coset containing $A$. Then show that $d$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: for (a) don't we need $\displaystyle \cup_{h \in H}Uh$ to be a countable union?

Comment: @gary: **All** unions of open sets are open.